Prevent automatic Spring OAuth2 redirect
I am trying to follow along the Spring Boot OAuth2 example, which sadly seems to be a bit outdated. The article describes a simple Spring Boot application that outsources login to an OAuth 2.0 authentication provider, which is GitHub in this example. Now, as soon as the pom.xml gets a new dependency
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>

and the according github settings in the application.yml
spring:
  application:
    name: MyTestApp
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          github:
            clientId: 983rkjhsaf809faj3
            clientSecret: 0af98s09gdf8sj3l5rjadsf98a7fdvdsaf

the behavior changes in a way that calling http://localhost:8080 automatically redirects to the GitHub OAuth 2.0 login page. After having logged in, a redirect sends the user back to http://localhost:8080 as a logged in user, showing the contents of the index.html defined in the project.
This is good so far, but maybe the root directory of http://localhost:8080 which is "/" should also be viewed by users that are not logged in. Sending them to the GitHub login page would be wrong. Therefore, the article offers to extend the code with a class WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter, and this class does not exist anymore for the current Spring Security version which is 6.4.1. I guess the example shown is for Spring Security 5 (?).
Therefore, I tried to add the security configuration the new way, using SecurityFilterChain.
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
                .requestMatchers("/", "/error", "/webjars/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
            )
            .exceptionHandling(e -> e
                .authenticationEntryPoint(new HttpStatusEntryPoint(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED))
            )
            .oauth2Login((oauth2Login) -> oauth2Login
                .userInfoEndpoint((userInfo) -> userInfo
                    .userAuthoritiesMapper(grantedAuthoritiesMapper())
                )
            );
        return http.build();
    }

    private GrantedAuthoritiesMapper grantedAuthoritiesMapper() {
        return (authorities) -> {
            Set<GrantedAuthority> mappedAuthorities = new HashSet<>();

            authorities.forEach((authority) -> {
                GrantedAuthority mappedAuthority;

                if (authority instanceof OAuth2UserAuthority) {
                    OAuth2UserAuthority userAuthority = (OAuth2UserAuthority) authority;
                    mappedAuthority = new OAuth2UserAuthority("OAUTH2_USER", userAuthority.getAttributes());
                } else {
                    mappedAuthority = authority;
                }

                mappedAuthorities.add(mappedAuthority);
            });

            return mappedAuthorities;
        };
    }
}

Here I clearly declare "/" with permitAll(), which should "Specify that URLs are allowed by anyone." Therefore, I would not expect Spring to redirect the user to the GitHub login page. But it does! The article also suggests to add an .exceptionHandling(...) method and send UNAUTHORIZED if called. But now I always get the HTTP ERROR 401 when calling http://localhost:8080.
What I want to achieve is very simple:

I want users to always be able to call http://localhost:8080 (hence, pointing to "/") regardless if logged in or not.
If users call any URL other than those defined for permitAll(), I want them to get the HTTP ERROR 401.

How can I do that? Which part of the security filter chain messes up this idea?

Sure, here is the GitHub repo: https://github.com/TheRealSocrates/oauth2-example

I believe it shouldn't be "/", but probably "index.html"

@JoaquinSantana It has the same result. When calling http://localhost:8080 I see HTTP ERROR 401 when not logged in, instead of seeing the page content.

When accessing http://localhost:8080, because we do not define a mapping request for /, the request matches the WelcomePageHandlerMapping, and it will forward to /index.html, and /index.html cannot pass the security filter,unless also add it permit like so:
 .requestMatchers("/", "/error", "/webjars/**", "/index.html").permitAll()

